# How to apply sub-filter in logstash

Tags: filter, logstash

the logstash allows to extract patterns via grok filter. My question is how I can use it in sub-sequent filter? For instance, the apache log provides the URI path of the query, something like `/path/api?param1=1&param2`. I can extract the whole thing in grok filter and assign to attribute `request`. Now I want to decompose it into different parts. My question is how I can use `request` attribute and split it further in order to get `/path`, `api`, `params`? Can someone provide an example?
Thanks,
Valentin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a second `grok` filter on a newly created field, like this:

```
grok {
   match => { "request" => Your pattern here }
}
```